# How is the better way to create background loop routines in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsthread, performselector

I need to create a routine that save automatically a file content in a constant time period, ie, a backgroung loop that perform the save instructions. I thinked in use a recursive call of performSelector like below:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self performSelector:@selector(saveMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:kTimeConstant];

}

- (void)saveMethod{

     //The save logic should to be here

     [self performSelector:@selector(saveMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:kTimeConstant];

}
```

It works, but when I get out of viewController, it still running, and it must to stop.
are there any better way to execute it? Thank you!

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't do anything in the background (ie. in a separate thread). Do you actually want to the save to happen on a non-main thread?

Comment: If you don't want it to be execute, then you can cancel @selector method in `viewWillDissapear:` method. And this is not background method. It will call in main thread after delay.

Comment: I have a RichtextEditor, and I want to implement a autosaving that in a time period save the html content, but it doesn`t can lock the execution, to be invisible to the user, so I think that it should`t run in the Main Thread.

Comment: Thank you The Tiger for the explanation. I really don't know much about it.

Comment: And why it shouldn't run in main thread ?? Have you done anything for this ? If you want it in background then you should use [– performSelectorInBackground:withObject:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelectorInBackground:withObject:)

Comment: Your requirement is not possible with single line method. You will have to run delay method in background. See below answer for how to run method in background.

Comment: The Tiger, the used cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget and it works fine! I still use the recursive call. Do you Agree that it is the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a better implementation:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // Start timer and sets it to a property called saveTimer
    self.saveTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                              target:self
                            selector:@selector(saveMethod:)
                            userInfo:nil
                             repeats:YES];
}

- (void)saveMethod:(NSTimer*)theTimer {
     // The save logic should to be here
     // No recursion
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    // Stop timer
    [self.saveTimer invalidate];
}
```

This is running on the main thread so it is probably not the best implementation but it should work better than what you currently have.

Comment: it looks interesting for me. Thank you Firo!

Comment: I would not say it better implementation.

Comment: It really works fine, but the invalidade does't is stopping the timer =(

Comment: Thats what I'm trying to tell. Happy you got it :)

Comment: I know that it works like above, yet the documentation on `NSTimer` clearly states "The selector must correspond to a method that returns void and takes a single argument".

Comment: @LucioFonseca I made a correction, thanks @NikolaiRuhe. It looks like `invalidate` works only if the method parameter list is correct. Look at my fix on the method (also make sure you add the `:` to `@selector(saveMethod:)`. If the `invalidate` still does not work for some reason try setting the timer to nil.

Answer (score 2):

There is a function `NSRunLoop cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:selector:object:` which allows you to cancel the performSelector call. Call this when you unload the view controller

ie.

```
 [NSRunLoop cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(saveMethod) object:nil];
```